# How can I access environment variables declared in Dockerfile?

Tags: tomcat, docker, dockerfile

How can i access the env variable (USER) declared in Dockerfile?

Dockerfile:

```
(...)    
ENV USER="username"
```

For example I have to read them out in my context.xml configuration File of Tomcat:

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    (...)
    username="$USER"
    (...)
/>
```

Does anybody knows the syntax?

Comment: This really isn't a docker question. You're asking how to use an environment variable that's been defined in your environment from inside of your Tomcat context.xml. The same answer would apply inside or outside of docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment Variables can be declared like:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Ddatabase.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:3306/projectname?useSSL=false
```

And than de Variable can be used in the context.xml like:

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
(...)
username="${USER}"
(...)
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

ENV variables couldn't be injected into the file `context.xml` without any actions.

You can do the following:

**1.**

Put some well known pattern inside your `context.xml` file like `username=USERNAME_TO_CHANGE` and change it during building of a docker image:

```
RUN sed -i "s/username=USERNAME_TO_CHANGE/username=$USER/g" context.xml
```

**2.**

Use [envsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/envsubst-Invocation.html) which will replace the environment variables in your file with their corresponding values. For that you need to install `gettext` package in your image and re-name `context.xml` to `context.xml-template` for example. After that you just do the following in the `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN envsubst < context.xml-template > context.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Declere like this.`ENV USER "UserName"`

Comment: I know how to declare it. But how can i access the variable in the context.xml?